# Replacing empty values in a CSV file using PHP when inserting data into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, insert

I currently have an issue where when I attempt to insert data from a CSV file into a MySQL database using PHP I get an error that is caused by empty fields within the CSV file.

In each row of data that has at least one empty field, it produces an error and doesn't insert the whole row into the database due to the empty field(s).

I was wondering if anybody knows how to find each empty field within the CSV file and populate them before they are inserted ("0" for empty int fields and "N/A" for empty varchar fields) without going through the CSV file and filling in the data manually.

**Code for inserting the data into database**

```
foreach($gymarr as $row){
    $day = $row[0];
    $routine= $row[1];
    $time= $row[2];
    $type= $row[3];
    $run= $row[4];
    $weights= $row[5];
    $tally= $row[6];


$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO Gym (day, routine, time, type, run, weights, tally) 
 VALUES ('$day', '$routine', $time, '$type', '$run', '$weights', tally)";

$result = $conn->query($sqlinsert);
```

Comment: What error exactly? It would be much more reliable if you used prepared statements and parameters to build the query - then you won't be vulnerable to things like apostrophes in the data, and likely to be less vulnerable to null/empty cells as well. https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli contains simple examples.

Comment: If the fields you're entering into the database are always going to have default values you'd be best setting a default value on each field within the database schema - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html. The you can just use a ternary when inserting... "$day = $row[0] ?? null;"

Comment: Post the exact error you are getting as we don't have the full picture without it. Have you set your table properties to allow null values?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' '50kg')' at line 4" I have tried manually filling in the data near this sections where it is empty and it resolved the issue, thats how I know that the issue is the empty cell in the CSV file

Comment: It's not entirely clear why that's causing the issue, since we can't see the rest of the query. If you dump `$sqlinsert` before you run it, we can see the whole thing and it's much easier to spot the error. But again, I suspect this would be resolved by using parameters anyway - please try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way is useful for you:

```
$day = $row[0] !== "" ? $row[0] : "n/a";
$routine= $row[1] !== "" ? $row[1] : "n/a";
$time= $row[2] !== "" ? $row[2] : "n/a";
$type= $row[3] !== "" ? $row[3] : "n/a";
$run= $row[4] !== "" ? $row[4] : "n/a";
$weights= $row[5] !== "" ? $row[5] : "n/a";
$tally= $row[6] !== "" ? $row[6] : "n/a";
```

You can replace "n/a" with "0" if needed.

Comment: I also had to add a real_escape_string to certain fields as there are characters which are causing problems with the SQL syntax. Is it possible to also have real_escape_string added to the code that you just sent?  The current code: $run= $conn->real_escape_string($row[4]);

Comment: @SnrJava sure - that's always a good ideo to escape strings.

Comment: I'm not sure how to actually format it within the same line, or does it need to be done separately from the code that you sent?

Comment: WARNING: `empty` can be surprising !! `'0'` IS empty. It is safer to check for an empty string `$day === ""` etc...

Comment: @Fravadona you're definitivly right! Updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Empty values are valid for sql insertion. The error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near ' '50kg')' at line 4"

means that the values themselves are breaking your query due to syntax. If you bind the values then the database will have the query and values separated and your source should no longer be breaking the values. Mysql allows empty `''`.

The correct, best and safest way to resolve your problem is with bound parameters. The following function I wrote some years back have simplified this type of work for me and they prevent sql from being contaminated by the values.

functions:

```
function dbConnect($dbname,$username,$password,$servername = "localhost"){
    if(empty($dbname) || empty($username) || empty($password)) return "Undefined database, username or password.";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;charset=utf8;dbname=".$dbname, $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
        return $conn;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        return "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

function dbQuery($conn,$sql="", $parameters=array(),$constant = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
    try{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        return $e;
    }
    foreach($parameters as $key=>$value) $stmt->bindValue( $key+1, $value);
    try{
        $stmt->execute(); 
        if ($stmt->columnCount() > 0){
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll($constant); //in cases of select something, return the rows.
        } else {
            $result = $stmt->rowCount();//in case of update/insert/delete statements: get number of rows affected
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $result = $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The code:

```
$conn = dbConnect($dbname,$username,$password,$servername);//you have to populate these values yourself

foreach($gymarr as $row){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Gym (day, routine, time, type, run, weights, tally) 
     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $result = dbQuery($conn, $sql,$row);//row is any flat, two dimensional array. It must have the same number of values as the number of '?' in your sql for each one to bind to and in the order that those columns appear in your query.
}
```

If you prefer to MySQLi as your database connection then see https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp.